# Notes on CSS Issue in IE7/8 & Hashchange plugin

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float, hashchange

http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/#press/index.htm
http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/#contact/index.htm

why are these floats breaking in IE?

and also, does anyone have any experience with 'jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js'
how to get the hashchange to not be so.. ugly?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are *quite a few* problems with this page.

I decided to try to make it look acceptable in Firefox, and wrote down what I did as I was doing it.

After applying all these changes using Firebug, [this page](http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/#press/index.htm) looks much better in Firefox.

- To `<section id="page">` add `overflow:auto`
- From `<footer>` remove `top: -32px`
- From the `<img>` inside `<div class="leftfloat">` remove `padding-top:12px`
- From `<div style="padding-top:75px">` make these changes:

  - Remove `padding-top: 75px`
  - Add `padding: 40px 0 15px 0`
  - Add `overflow: auto`
  - Add `width: 100%`
- On the first `<article>`: `<article class="leftfloat" style="clear: left; width: 275px;">`
  change the `width` to `250px`.
- On the second `<article>`: `<article class="leftfloat" style="width: 250px;">` add `padding: 0 25px 0 0`.

Like I said, there are rather a lot of problems with this page. Apply those changes, and let's see how it's looking in IE.

---

Viewing source here: http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/press/index.htm, I see unparsed PHP tags:

```
<?php
 include_once 'includes/header.inc';
?>
...
<?php
 include_once 'includes/footer.inc';
?>
```

They shouldn't be there. (I got that URL by looking at the XHR request section in Firebug.)